# Query to tell me if customer is in 3 queries

Tags: ms-access

I have three queries;

Q1. Returns all customer records (id, name, year amount) where the customer has spent money with us.
Q2. Returns all customers records (id,name, year of regis, number) where the customer has a telephone number.
Q3. Returns all customer records (id,name, year, amount) where the customer has a purchased a specific product.

I want a new query that will return a list of all customers ids, names if they appear in any of the 3 queries, along with the latest year. How do I do that?

Comment: sounds like you need a UNION query.

Comment: Sounds like you need a WHERE EXISTS. Your question however is not clear neither does it include an example as per the forum guide lines: [How to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add all the results of the 3 queries together using `UNION`, then group the records by `id` and select the first name (or any name really, because they must be all the same) and the maximum year.

Try this:

```
SELECT id, FIRST(name), MAX(year)
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, year FROM q1
    UNION
    SELECT id, name, year FROM q2
    UNION
    SELECT id, name, year FROM q3) AS q
GROUP BY id
```